# Chatbot implementation for Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, artificial-intelligence, wit.ai

Is there any way to implement/integrate the chatbox for ionic application?

I have gone through various options including:

- Wit.ai
- Facebook Messenger

Though i am able to create a bot using FB messenger, I am not to view that properly on my mobile device.

Also, i have implemented the wit.ai(with node.js). But not able to deploy/use the same node on my front end device(Ionic).

Can anyone help me for the same.

Comment: Have gotten any further on your research?

Comment: @RodrigoRubio yes i was able to create the FB messenger. But i switched to api.ai, as i was much more easlier for me to integrate in my ionic application, with better control. I was able to customize(the UI), and created a custom chat UI which is functioning properly.

Comment: interesting! thank you :-) might look into it.

Comment: I am also interested in creating a chatbot for ionic2 application